# Librería Docxpresso elimina el signo & ampersand

Tags: php

Estoy usando la librería de Docxpresso para poder generar archivos de texto en PHP, en este caso archivos en Word. Por ahora no tengo la licencia completa de Docxpresso por lo que de manera gratuita ofrece archivos con extensión .odt. Al renderizar me doy cuenta que elimina algunos signos por ejemplo: "<", "&", los cuales necesito que aparezca en el texto de word. Tuviste el mismo error?, pudiste solucionarlo? dejo mi código abajo.

```php
$html = '
  <style>
       * {font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt}
  </style>

  <p style="text-align: center;"><strong><u>MINUTA >> << &&&</u></strong></p>';

$doc = new Docxpresso\createDocument();
$format = '.odt'; //solo uso .odt ya que no tengo licencia de docxpresso

$doc->html(array('html'=>$html, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8'));

$doc->render('sample' . $format);

header('Location: ../creditogarveh/sample'.$format);
```

Actualmente el resultado que obtengo en el archivo final es algo así:

"MINUTA >>", pero debería salir de esta manera: "MINUTA >> << &&&".

Comment: Quizá existe un conflicto de codificación de caracteres y no reconoce el (&), por lo tanto, intenta colocarlo no como signo, sino como su código HTML nativo, así: &#38;. Es decir: `<u>MINUTA >> << &#38;&#38;&#38;</u>`

Comment: Muy bueno amigo, lo hice queda bien. Pensé que se podía modificar en alguna parte de la librería, ya que esto se debe a que tengo CLIENTES COMO EMPRESA, y sus nombres son algo así: J & M PRODUCCIONES, por lo que salía: J M (sin &) y eso es un gran error en temas legales. Tendría que reemplazar todo (&) por (&#38;), ya que no habría de otra me parece verdad? gracias amigo por tu apoyo de antemano muy bueno.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Justo pasé alguna vez por ese inconveniente, y no he hayado otra manera de que internamente me reconosca los `&` con símbolo, entonces opté por cambiarlos a su código HTML puro cómo te comenté `&#38;`. Ahora, si en diferentes partes del nombre  de la empresa aparece el símbolo `&`, sería recomendable reemplazar todos los `&` por `&#38;` con `str_replace();`, con eso no tendrías que cambiar uno por uno.

```
$html = '
  <style>
      * {font-family: Arial; font-size: 8pt}
  </style>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><strong><u>MINUTA >> << &&&</u</strong></p>';

$nombre_empresa = str_replace('&', '&#38;', $html);

echo $nombre_empresa;
```